# Not able to fetch contacts from Salesforce

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am trying ti fetch Salesforce contacts. I am using Python for coding. But the error belongs to some kind of permission in enabling in Salesforce . I have signed up as developer in salesforce (Selected developer form drop down @ sign up form).

Error I am getting is :

**The REST API is not enabled for this Organization.**

```
Request refused for https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id%2C+Name%2C+Email+FROM+Contact. Response content: [{'errorCode': 'API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG', 'message': 'The REST API is not enabled for this Organization.'}]
```

Here is my profile, app looks like .

[image]
[image]

I have selected all permission for my app and here they looks like when authenticating user.

**My Organization Edition**

```
Developer Edition
```

**EDIT :**

I don't have enough reputation to comment , So I am writing my issue here.
Earlier the issue was because of professional edition offcorse, I changed to Developer edition and changed client id etc to in my code but my browser was cached so I was still getting the same issue as soon as I tried it in private browsing The issue gets resolved.

Comment: Can you check if "API Enabled" is turned on on your profile?

Comment: Have you tried - API enabled via Manage Users > Permission Set > System Permission?

Comment: You should probably post that as an answer rather than an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment , So I am writing my issue here.

Earlier the issue was because of **professional edition** offcorse, I changed to Developer edition and changed client id etc to in my code but my browser was cached so I was still getting the same issue as soon as I tried it in private browsing The issue gets resolved.